# Symfony and PhpStorm twig gives me no suggestions for twig functions

Tags: twig, phpstorm, symfony

I have Symfony projects in both version 2.7 and 3.1. PhpStorm has the Symfony Plugin and Twig Support plugin enabled.

When I work in the Symfony 2.7 version PhpStorm with  give me suggestion for Twig output tags {{ }} like assets and dump etc.

The 3.1 version gives me no suggestions. Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: What version of PHPStorm are you using? I'm using 9.0.2 and also have a Symfony 3 project on the go and the tags auto-complete for me.

Comment: I use 2016.2.2.

Comment: That looks like a date to me...what version is it? 7? 8?

Comment: Okay I solved it. Althought the plugin was enabled in "Settings"->"Pluging" it had to be enabled via the Event log. It showed me a message: "Symfony Plugin: Enable the Symfony Plugin with auto configuration now, open Project Settings or dismiss further messages".

Comment: The Event Log doesn't control the plugins, it probably just showed you a warning linking you to the Settings. But good you got a sorted.

Comment: @MichaelEmerson ever since phpstorm went subscription, their version numbers are now basically YEAR.MAJOR.MINOR - just FYI. The version OP is using is the latest.

Answer (score 8):

In `File => Settings => Languages & Frameworks => Symfony`, configure the project as follows:

[image]

And Restart phpStorm.

Dont forget to install symfony plugin

As noted by [select0r](https://stackoverflow.com/users/255905/select0r) - Starting with PHPStorm 2021.1 you'll find the above settings under:
`File => Settings => PHP => Symfony`

Comment: Note that starting with PHPStorm 2021.1 you'll finde the above settings under File => Settings => PHP => Symfony.

Comment: For me I just needed to tick the "Enable" at the top. You'd think it would be auto enabled after installing the plugin.

Answer (score 1):

in addition to @adashbob's answer.

make sure that the file mappings in the symfony plugin settings are correct.

2.7 and 3.0 use a different location for cache files.

```
2.7 - app/cache
3.0 - var/cache
```

the plugin isn't intelligent enough to know which version youre running.

Comment: where do you set the cache location in the plugin? (in the 2021 version)

Answer (score 0):

You usually need to trigger the AutoComplete pop-up yourself by pressing CTRL + SPACE (this might be a different shortcut depending on your keyboard).
Check your file -> Settings -> Languages and framework -> PHP -> Symfony -> Activate the plugin for this project